# NY Times API, JSON, and Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, api, rubygems

I am attempting to pull NY Times Bestseller info from their API to then parse and print out all pretty with Ruby.

For some reason, it isn't working. Probably because I'm an idiot? Please be kind. I'm a total beginner.

```
runner.rb
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'
require_relative 'books.rb'

result = RestClient.get('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v2/lists/Combined-Print-and-E-Book-Fiction.json?&offset=&sortby=&sortorder=&api-key=**********************')
parsed = JSON.parse result

books = parsed["results"].each do |results_hash|
 results_hash["book_details"].collect do |s|
  Bestseller.new s["title"], s["description"], s["author"]
 end
end

puts "Here's some books"
books.each do |infos|
 puts infos
end

books.rb
class Bestseller
  def initialize title, description, author
    @title = title
    @description = description
    @author = author
  end
end
```

OK, so took suggestion below. Error is gone. But now the books variable is displaying things I don't want. I only want title, description, author.

```
[{"list_name"=>"Combined Print and E-Book Fiction", "display_name"=>"Combined Print & E-Book Fiction", "updated"=>"WEEKLY", "bestsellers_date"=>"2013-11-02", "published_date"=>"2013-11-17", "list_image"=>"9781101626368.jpg", "normal_list_ends_at"=>15, "rank"=>1, "rank_last_week"=>0, "weeks_on_list"=>1, "asterisk"=>0, "dagger"=>0, "isbns"=>[{"isbn10"=>"0425259854", "isbn13"=>"9780425259856"}], "book_details"=>[{"title"=>"DARK WITCH", "description"=>"In the first book of the Cousins O'Dwyer trilogy, Iona Sheehan moves to Ireland to investigate her family's history.", "contributor"=>"by Nora Roberts", "author"=>"Nora Roberts"
```

If you want/need to look at the raw json data, it's here: http://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v2/lists/Combined-Print-and-E-Book-Fiction.json?&offset=&sortby=&sortorder=&api-key=6504A37DEA8BB8DC7B13807A5DA44D16:17:68383866

Adding hash example back:

```
{"status"=>"OK", 
"copyright"=>"Copyright (c) 2013 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved.", 
"num_results"=>25, 
"last_modified"=>"2013-11-08T13:15:36-05:00", 
"results"=>
    [
      {"list_name"=>"Combined Print and E-Book Fiction", 
      "display_name"=>"Combined Print & E-Book Fiction", 
      "updated"=>"WEEKLY", 
      "bestsellers_date"=>"2013-11-02", 
      "published_date"=>"2013-11-17", 
      "list_image"=>"9781101626368.jpg", 
      "normal_list_ends_at"=>15, "
      rank"=>1, 
      "rank_last_week"=>0, 
      "weeks_on_list"=>1, 
      "asterisk"=>0, 
      "dagger"=>0, 
      "isbns"=>
        [
          {"isbn10"=>"0425259854", 
          "isbn13"=>"9780425259856"}
        ], 
      "book_details"=> 
        [
          {"title"=>"DARK WITCH", 
          "description"=>"In the first book of the Cousins O'Dwyer trilogy, Iona Sheehan moves to Ireland to investigate her family's history.", 
          "contributor"=>"by Nora Roberts", 
          "author"=>"Nora Roberts",
```

Comment: Which line of that code is throwing the error?  Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Having trouble accessing the keys inside of book_details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're parsing the results correctly.  `results` is an array which contains a hash with a key of `book_details`.  So, you'd want something like:

```
books = parsed["results"].each do |results_hash|
  results_hash["book_details"].map do |book_details_hash|
    book = Bestseller.new book_details_hash["title"], book_details_hash["description"], book_details_hash["author"]

    book.save!
  end
end
```

The addition above sets the `Bestseller` to the variable book and then saves it.  An alternative would be to use `Bestseller.create` instead of `Bestseller.new`.

Comment: Well that got rid of the error! But now I get an insane result that's more than I wanted:

Comment: '[{"list_name"=>"Combined Print and E-Book Fiction", "display_name"=>"Combined Print & E-Book Fiction", "updated"=>"WEEKLY",' and so on

Comment: I don't think at this point you want `collect`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it. It's still giving everything inside of the results array instead of just the book_details values specified. I think there's some more layers of arrays/hashes?

Comment: Yeah, without the hash example in the question it'll be hard to troubleshoot at this point.  Can you add that back?